# PowerBI new column calculation based on columns from different tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate 'TimeSheet Team PV'[Time (h)] * 'Position History'[Salary]

Data model:
[image]
TimeSheet Team PV" table:
[image]
"Position History" table:
[image]

In the Position History table, I have some employees which were promoted and appear as having different periods during different periods in the company, with different salary. Can I join somehow these values based on Start Date, End Date (Position History table) and Work Date (TimeSheet Team PV tables) + Name?

I would like to generate new column in the TimeSheet Team PV table, with the calculation above.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write some logic to make sure it uses the `Work Date` column. Something like this:

```
Cost =
VAR WorkDate = 'TimeSheet Team PV'[Work Date]
RETURN
    'TimeSheet Team PV'[Time (h)]
        * CALCULATE (
            SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Position History'[Salary] ),
            'Position History'[Start Date] <= WorkDate,
            'Position History'[End Date] >= WorkDate
        )
```

Comment: In that case, please accept the solution to mark it as resolved.